# eofs.xarray raising TypeError (Using a DataArray to construct a variable is ambiguous)

Tags: python, python-xarray

I'm working on a multidimensional dataset using xarray and had some issues with [eofs, the EOF analysis package](https://ajdawson.github.io/eofs/latest/index.html), and particularly, with its [xarray interface](https://ajdawson.github.io/eofs/latest/api/eofs.xarray.html#module-eofs.xarray).

My xarray DataArray looks like this:

```
<xarray.DataArray 'timeMonthly_avg_flux' (time: 1800, y: 601, x: 601)>
array([[[0., 0., ..., 0., 0.],
    [0., 0., ..., 0., 0.],
    ...,
    [0., 0., ..., 0., 0.],
    [0., 0., ..., 0., 0.]],
   [[0., 0., ..., 0., 0.],
    [0., 0., ..., 0., 0.],
    ...,
    [0., 0., ..., 0., 0.],
    [0., 0., ..., 0., 0.]]])
Coordinates:
lat      (y, x) float64 ...
lon      (y, x) float64 ...
time     (time) datetime64[ns] 2001-01-31 2001-02-28 ... 2150-12-31
x        (x) float64 -3e+06 -2.99e+06 -2.98e+06 ... 2.98e+06 2.99e+06 3e+06
y        (y) float64 -3e+06 -2.99e+06 -2.98e+06 ... 2.98e+06 2.99e+06 3e+06
```

The problem arises when I run the following:

```
from eofs.xarray import Eof
solver = Eof(flux) # flux is the above DataArray
flux_eofs = solver.eofs()
```

for which I get the following TypeError:

```
TypeError: Using a DataArray object to construct a variable is ambiguous, please extract the data using the .data property.
```

Also noting that other methods in this function work as intended: I am able to call the principal components as below:

```
flux_pcs = solver.pcs()
```

The dataset does have NaN values, but as far as I can tell, the eofs.xarray module has been designed to handle NaNs. For now, my workaround has been to convert the dataset into a Numpy array and use the [eofs.standard interface](https://ajdawson.github.io/eofs/latest/api/eofs.standard.html#eofs.standard.Eof) instead, and convert the outputs back into xarray Datasets/DataArrays as required. All methods work as intended when I do this:

```
from eofs.standard import Eof
flux_np = flux.to_numpy()
solver = Eof(flux_np)
flux_eofs = solver.eofs()
```

I could find two other instances of this error being raised: as part of the [w2w package](https://github.com/matthiasdemuzere/w2w/issues/11), where it seems to have been something to do with the python environment, and here, as part of the [PyWake project](https://gitlab.windenergy.dtu.dk/TOPFARM/PyWake/-/merge_requests/308), but it's not clear to me what the problem was.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For everyone encountering this issue, this is a bug which has been also raised  and discussed on [Github](https://github.com/ajdawson/eofs/issues/123) (also by the author of this question :)). The xarray compability is a bit broken currently.

For the time being this can be fixed manually by changing the

`eofs/lib/eofs/xarray.py` - file

```
#Lines 638 to 640
# Add non-dimension coordinates. 
pcs.coords.update({coord.name: (coord.dims, coord)
                       for coord in time_ndcoords})
```

to

```
# Add non-dimension coordinates.
pcs.coords.update({coord.name: (coord.dims, coord.data)
                       for coord in time_ndcoords})
```

There is a [pull request](https://github.com/ajdawson/eofs/pull/124) fixing this that has unfortunately not been merged yet.

Comment: accepting this as the best solution right now, until compatibility is taken care of.

Answer (score 1):

I recently ran into the same error message in my project (it is different in nature to yours). I pip uninstalled the latest version of xarray on my PC (0.20.2) and installed an older version (0.16.0), and (at least) that error went away.

Comment: While this works, those seeking to use the latest xarray version might prefer the accepted answer that points to a manual fix in the eofs codebase

Comment: For sure, I just remembered running into the same error message and came across this post hoping for an answer as well, so once I found something that worked (as a temporary fix) I wanted to share it. It’s great that the accepted answer allows the latest xarray to work properly!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the shameless self-promotion ;) you may want to give [xeofs](https://github.com/nicrie/xeofs) a try. It provides EOF analysis (and more) in `xarray`.

Comment: Been experimenting with it, the PCA implementation suits my needs very well